# supporting bilingual application struts framework

Tags: jsp, unicode, character-encoding, struts, arabic

I am currently working on a Bilingual application (English and Arabic) with struts framework.

My application is currently built to support English characters.

Now am trying to post and read UTF-8 encoded characters on my JSP pages in Tomcat 6 environment.

So i have the basic things set up in all my jsp pages and  action class.

I have set this in my action class

```
            `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("UTF-8");`
```

In my jsp pages: `<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>`

So when i try to post Arabic characters to my jsp page, it displays junk characters.

How do i correct it? what else do i need to do to support arabic or chinese characters?

Also, am using a database to save the form once the user fills out the application. The user can either use English or arablic to fill the form.

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Ok i can post characters to my jsp page now. This is what i did before posting a string to my Jsp page.  String str = (some chinese character) string newString = new String(str.getBytes(),"UTF-8"); But i assumed my action class would do it for me after i set response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"). Is there a better way to do it? Am still having problems when i recieve chinese characters from the form though. I might have to convert it to UTF-8 explicity, but i guess there is a better way.. Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do only two things to get UTF-8 to work for POST forms.

Put this in top of JSP:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Put this in a `Filter` which runs **before** your action class.

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Doing this inside the action class might be already too late. It should be set *before* you or any MVC framework gathers the request parameters.

Comment: Then the problem is in the way how you displayed the characters. How are you displaying them? This article may help in getting the one and other straight: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Comment: @BalusC: I have added filter class and mapped in web.xml also i have the page encoding set t0 UTF-8. Now i want to add the form elements like name , city  to my database.  In my action class i get the values by form.getName() and compare it with a array of unicode characters.                             For doing this, should i first explicitly convert form.getName  to UTF using  newString str= new String(form.getName().getBytes(),"UTF-8"). Cos when i print out form.getname() it prints ???? ????.

Comment: @BalusC: I have one more question. I am using Ms sql server. I have columns defined as ntext and Nvarchar to accept utf-8.I have a float column to accept amount, but the user can enter the amount in chinese. How do i change this column to accept amount in chinese?

Comment: I'd just write a converter to convert it to latin numbers and vice versa or maybe restrict the enduser to enter latin numbers only. Chinese do understand it as well, do they? Otherwise you really need to use a text/char column.

Comment: They do understand, but cant restrict them to Latin numbers only.. Will use a ntext column. Thanks for ur help ..

Comment: @BalusC: My application works fine in localhost(windows machine), but when i deploy the same app in unix box, the unicode characters are all messed up(junk characters). Any idea??